# Can Nop Commerce Plugins that have "Supported Version: 3.8" work on a Nop Commerce 3.7 install?

Tags: plugins, themes, e-commerce, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-themes

We purchased a theme for our client's Nop Commerce website, and the plugins weren't showing up in the admin. So I started digging, and they say "Supported Version 3.8" and the install that our client is running is 3.7

Are they not showing up because of the version mismatch, and is there a way to get the plugins to work / show up on nop commerce 3.7?

Answer (score 0):

> "Supported Version 3.8" and the install that our client is running is
>   3.7

Obviously, You cannot use 3.8 version plugin into 3.7 running website.

**Why?**

Because, basically there are many major changes done in nopCommerce 3.80 and which is not available in nopCommerce 3.70.

> is there a way to get the plugins to work / show up on nop commerce
>   3.7

Here are two different thing, *show up* and *work*.

For just show on admin side, you have to change version of your plugin in plugin description file `Description.txt`.

`SupportedVersions: 3.80` to `3.70`

But this will only display plugin on admin side but when you install it, will give you a bunch of errors.

*So, what can i do, for work?*

You can do this manually downgrade your plugin version to remove changes of 3.80, but for that necessary thing is, you should have source code of plugin.

If you have only production code of plugin then you cannot do this as far as i know!